# Issue with dropdown content change

Tags: javascript, html

At the load of page all the contents are visible. Want the particular dropdown value only show but now the three tabs are shown at the page load.

```
<select onchange="openCity(event, this.value)">
<option>Select search option</option>
<option>To Rent</option>
<option>To Sale</option>
</select>
<div id="Select search option" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="To Rent" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
</div>

<div id="To Sale" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<script>
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your script is hiding all the tabs inside your `openCity()` function which isn't called when the page is first loaded, only when the `<select>` is changed.

You need to move the code that hides your tabs outside the `openCity()` function, into its own function you can call multiple times.

```
// pre-cache these values outside your function
var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
var tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");

// reusable hide function you can call multiple times
function hideAllTabs() {
    for (var i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}
hideAllTabs();

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    hideAllTabs();

    for (var i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

However, an even simpler approach would be to simply use CSS to hide all the tabs. Then your `active` class can be told to change the `display` CSS property to `block` so that it shows itself only when active.

```
<style>
    /* hide all tabs by default */
    .tabcontent {
        display: none;
    }

    /* only show the active tab */
    .active {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

You can then remove that `hideAllTabs()` function completely because you're using pure CSS to hide and show the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a change event on select list on document load.

```js
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
e.dispatchEvent(evt);
    OR
// Create a new 'change' event
var event = new Event('change');
e.dispatchEvent(event);
```